# How to speed up MySQL Select Case query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, case

I'm using this same format for several other SQL queries that I've developed with the help of another SO user. It works wonderfully on tables where there aren't too many rows, but I'm now working on getting this query to work with 3 tables that have about 65K rows each. The query has yet to finish running (I let it run in the background while I work on other things, and give up after about 8 hours). The same query runs in a few minutes on tables with around 20K rows. I've tried creating indexes on my tables on the join fields (both 1 index with multiple fields, and separate single field indexes) and still no luck. I'm wondering if there are other ways I can optimize this query, or perhaps another approach I can take to get a similar result.

```
SELECT a.PART_KIT_ID, `PART_KIT_NAME`,`EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`, `ATA_NUMBER`, `PART_KIT_DESC`, `ACTIVE_IND`, `Flag NameA`, `Parameter Name`, `Flag NameB`, `AutoCAT`, `ICAM`, `ICAM_PRIOR`
 from (SELECT b.PART_KIT_ID
, CASE WHEN b.CTLG_VER_ID <> c.CTLG_VER_ID and b.CTLG_VER_ID <> a.CTLG_VER_ID THEN 'CTLG VER ID FLAG A' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.CTLG_VER_ID = c.CTLG_VER_ID and b.CTLG_VER_ID <> a.CTLG_VER_ID THEN 'CTLG VER ID FLAG B' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, d.ATA_NUMBER `ATA_NUMBER`
, d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
, d.ACTIVE_IND `ACTIVE_IND`
, 'CTLG_VER_ID' `Parameter Name`
, a.CTLG_VER_ID `AutoCAT`
, b.CTLG_VER_ID `ICAM`
, c.CTLG_VER_ID `ICAM_PRIOR`
FROM cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_acat a
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = b.ATTRIB_ID
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = c.ATTRIB_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.ACAT_PART_KIT_ID = d.AUTOCAT_PART_KIT_ID 
UNION ALL
SELECT b.PART_KIT_ID 
, CASE WHEN b.CTLG_NAME <> c.CTLG_NAME and b.CTLG_NAME <> a.CTLG_NAME THEN 'CTLG NAME FLAG A' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.CTLG_NAME = c.CTLG_NAME and b.CTLG_NAME <> a.CTLG_NAME THEN 'CTLG NAME FLAG B' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, d.ATA_NUMBER `ATA_NUMBER`
, d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
, d.ACTIVE_IND `ACTIVE_IND`
, 'CTLG_NAME' `Parameter Name`  
, a.CTLG_NAME `AutoCAT`
, b.CTLG_NAME `ICAM`
, c.CTLG_NAME `ICAM_PRIOR`
FROM cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_acat a
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = b.ATTRIB_ID
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = c.ATTRIB_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.ACAT_PART_KIT_ID = d.AUTOCAT_PART_KIT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT b.PART_KIT_ID
, CASE WHEN b.PART_KIT_NAME <> c.PART_KIT_NAME and b.PART_KIT_NAME <> a.PART_KIT_NAME THEN 'PART KIT NAME FLAG A' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.PART_KIT_NAME = c.PART_KIT_NAME and b.PART_KIT_NAME <> a.PART_KIT_NAME THEN 'PART KIT NAME FLAG B' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, d.ATA_NUMBER `ATA_NUMBER`
, d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
, d.ACTIVE_IND `ACTIVE_IND`  
, 'PART_KIT_NAME' `Parameter Name`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `AutoCAT`
, b.PART_KIT_NAME `ICAM`
, c.PART_KIT_NAME `ICAM_PRIOR`
FROM cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_acat a
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = b.ATTRIB_ID
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = c.ATTRIB_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.ACAT_PART_KIT_ID = d.AUTOCAT_PART_KIT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT b.PART_KIT_ID
, CASE WHEN b.ATTRIB_ID <> c.ATTRIB_ID and b.ATTRIB_ID <> a.ATTRIB_ID THEN 'ATTRIB_ID FLAG A' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.ATTRIB_ID = b.ATTRIB_ID and b.ATTRIB_ID <> a.ATTRIB_ID THEN 'ATTRIB_ID ID FLAG B' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, d.ATA_NUMBER `ATA_NUMBER`
, d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
, d.ACTIVE_IND `ACTIVE_IND`  
, 'ATTRIB_ID' `Parameter Name`
, a.ATTRIB_ID `AutoCAT`
, b.ATTRIB_ID `ICAM`
, c.ATTRIB_ID `ICAM_PRIOR`
FROM cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_acat a
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = b.ATTRIB_ID
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = c.ATTRIB_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.ACAT_PART_KIT_ID = d.AUTOCAT_PART_KIT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT b.PART_KIT_ID
, CASE WHEN b.ATTRIB_NAME <> c.ATTRIB_NAME and b.ATTRIB_NAME <> a.ATTRIB_NAME THEN 'ATTRIB_NAME FLAGA' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.ATTRIB_NAME = c.ATTRIB_NAME and b.ATTRIB_NAME <> a.ATTRIB_NAME THEN 'ATTRIB_NAME FLAGB' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, d.ATA_NUMBER `ATA_NUMBER`
, d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
, d.ACTIVE_IND `ACTIVE_IND`  
, 'ATTRIB_NAME' `Parameter Name`
, a.ATTRIB_NAME `AutoCAT`
, b.ATTRIB_NAME `ICAM`
, c.ATTRIB_NAME `ICAM_PRIOR`
FROM cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_acat a
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = b.ATTRIB_ID
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = c.ATTRIB_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.ACAT_PART_KIT_ID = d.AUTOCAT_PART_KIT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT b.PART_KIT_ID
, CASE WHEN b.ATTRIB_DESC <> c.ATTRIB_DESC and b.ATTRIB_DESC <> a.ATTRIB_DESC THEN 'ATTRIB_DESC FLAGA' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.ATTRIB_DESC = c.ATTRIB_DESC and b.ATTRIB_DESC <> a.ATTRIB_DESC THEN 'ATTRIB_DESC FLAGB' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, d.ATA_NUMBER `ATA_NUMBER`
, d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
, d.ACTIVE_IND `ACTIVE_IND`  
, 'ATTRIB_DESC' `Parameter Name`
, a.ATTRIB_DESC `AutoCAT`
, b.ATTRIB_DESC `ICAM`
, c.ATTRIB_DESC `ICAM_PRIOR`
FROM cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_acat a
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = b.ATTRIB_ID
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = c.ATTRIB_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.ACAT_PART_KIT_ID = d.AUTOCAT_PART_KIT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT b.PART_KIT_ID
, CASE WHEN b.ATTRIB_VALUE <> c.ATTRIB_VALUE and b.ATTRIB_VALUE <> a.ATTRIB_VALUE THEN 'ATTRIB_VALUE FLAGA' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.ATTRIB_VALUE = c.ATTRIB_VALUE and b.ATTRIB_VALUE <> a.ATTRIB_VALUE THEN 'ATTRIB_VALUE FLAGB' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, d.ATA_NUMBER `ATA_NUMBER`
, d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
, d.ACTIVE_IND `ACTIVE_IND`  
, 'ATTRIB_VALUE' `Parameter Name`
, a.ATTRIB_VALUE `AutoCAT`
, b.ATTRIB_VALUE `ICAM`
, c.ATTRIB_VALUE `ICAM_PRIOR`
FROM cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_acat a
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = b.ATTRIB_ID
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = c.ATTRIB_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.ACAT_PART_KIT_ID = d.AUTOCAT_PART_KIT_ID 
UNION ALL
SELECT b.PART_KIT_ID
, CASE WHEN b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID <> c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID <> a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID THEN 'EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID FLAGA' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID <> a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID THEN 'EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID FLAGB' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, d.ATA_NUMBER `ATA_NUMBER`
, d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
, d.ACTIVE_IND `ACTIVE_IND`  
, 'EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID' `Parameter Name`
, a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `AutoCAT`
, b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `ICAM`
, c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `ICAM_PRIOR`
FROM cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_acat a
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = b.ATTRIB_ID
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = c.ATTRIB_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.ACAT_PART_KIT_ID = d.AUTOCAT_PART_KIT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT b.PART_KIT_ID
, CASE WHEN b.PART_KIT_ID <> c.PART_KIT_ID and b.PART_KIT_ID <> a.PART_KIT_ID THEN 'PART_KIT_ID FLAGA' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.PART_KIT_ID = c.PART_KIT_ID and b.PART_KIT_ID <> a.PART_KIT_ID THEN 'PART_KIT_ID FLAGB' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, d.ATA_NUMBER `ATA_NUMBER`
, d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
, d.ACTIVE_IND `ACTIVE_IND`  
, 'PART_KIT_ID' `Parameter Name`
, a.PART_KIT_ID `AutoCAT`
, b.PART_KIT_ID `ICAM`
, c.PART_KIT_ID `ICAM_PRIOR`
FROM cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_acat a
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = b.ATTRIB_ID
JOIN cost_part_kit_attrib_ctlg_pq_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.ATTRIB_ID = c.ATTRIB_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.ACAT_PART_KIT_ID = d.AUTOCAT_PART_KIT_ID 
  ) a
  ORDER BY PART_KIT_ID
```

Originally I had thought of using Unpivot, but was advised against that due to the number of fields I would be working with. Would love advice/suggestions frormthe experts!

Comment: We can't really help with performance without proper DDLs and an EXPLAIN

Answer (score 0):

So, I spent some time looking at my joins, trying to make sure that they really made sense - and I realized that my left outer join was joining on a field that didn't make as much sense as another field would. My query now runs in 1 minute and 16 seconds!